# Initialize Map onMount in React

Tags: reactjs, data-structures, react-hooks, setstate

I'm currently creating a react.js app with function components. I want to store some urls from my cloud storage inside a map data structure, so I can access them later in my html code. The problem is, that the values are not stored properly and I end up with an empty map, as you can see in the screenshot:

[Log output of: console.log("imageMap", imageMap) and
console.log("imageMap", imageMap.values())](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXOOx.png)

But inside my function the map is correct...

[log output of console.log("tmp", tmpMap)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiWdj.png)

Does anyone has an idea how to fix this?
Here is my code:

```
const [imageMap, setImageMap]  = useState(new Map());

useEffect(() => {

    const func = async () => {
        let tmpMap = imageMap
        const reference = ref(storage, "target-content")

        await listAll(reference)
            .then((res) => {
                res.items.forEach((itemRef) => {
                    getDownloadURL(itemRef).then((x) => {
                            tmpMap.set(itemRef.name, x)
                            console.log("tmp", tmpMap) //ok size: 18
                            setImageMap(tmpMap)
                        }
                    );
                });
            }).catch((error) => {
                // Uh-oh, an error occurred
            });
    }
    func();

    console.log("imageMap", imageMap) //size: 0, entries: 18?
    console.log("imageMap", imageMap.values())

}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

The map is correct in console.log because the browser remembers its reference and shows you a modified value. It happens because you actually mutate your imageMap; assigning it to tmpMap doesn't achieve what you'd like: imageMap is still being mutated.

React also doesn't recognize imageMap updated and doesn't rerender your component as you'd expect.

You could do `let tmpMap = new Map(imageMap)` to alleviate that, it's one of the ways to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `func()` is executed asynchronously while the following statements are executed. This means, that `console.log("imageMap", imageMap)` is executed (potentially) before `tmpMap.set(...)` is called in your asynchronous function.

The second problem is that `setImageMap(tmpMap)` does not do anything - it will will just replace a pointer to a map with the same pointer. You should instead create a new Map and assign `imageMap` to the newly created Map.

You can verify this by adding another useEffect hook to your code that reacts to changes is the `imageMap` state variable:

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log("imageMap", imageMap);
   console.log("imageMap", imageMap.values());
}, [imageMap]);
```

You will see that eventually, `imageMap` will be assigned to a new value.